# If you add HTML Elements to the DOM using Javascript's innerHTML is there a way to access those elements with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, global, innerhtml

I am trying to add more HTML elements to the DOM with a button's onclick using "innerHTML" and template literals. That much is working, but when I try to get access to the elements via a "getElementBy" or "querySelector", I can't; and I don't know why not. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Adding and grabbing HTML Elements</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <button id="add-character">Add</button>
    <div id="grid"></div>   

</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

** Javascript**

```
let grid=document.getElementById("grid")
console.log(grid)

const addCharacter=document.getElementById("add-character")
        console.log(addCharacter)

let Hp=0;

let num=0;

addCharacter.addEventListener("click",()=>{
grid.innerHTML+=`
    <div id="subgrid" class="subgrid">
    <br>
    <div id="status" class="status">Status</div>
    <br>
    <div id="iniative" class="iniative">Iniative</div>

    <input id="iniativeel" id="iniativeel" type="number">

    <button id="inativebtn" class="inativebtn">Submit</button>
    <br>
    <div id="character" class="character">Character</div>
    <br>
    <div id="healthpoints" class="healthpoints">Healthpoints</div>
    <br>
    <input id="initalHp" class="initalHp" type="number">
    <br>    
    <Button id="initalhp" class="initalhp">Submit</button>
    <br>
    <input id="damage" class="damage" type="number">
    <br>
    <button id ="damagebtn" class="damagebtn">Submit</button>
    <br>
    <div id="weapons" class="weapons">Weapons</div>
    </div>`
})

btn()
function btn(){
    let iniativeBtn=document.querySelector("#iniativebtn").textContent
    console.log(iniativeBtn)
}
```

Comment: There is a type in your 'id' and 'querySelector', you are looking for something that doesnt exist. "document.querySelector("#inativebtn")", but why not creating elements dynamically instead of literals?

Comment: your button in html has `id="inativebtn"` but then you call `document.querySelector("#iniativebtn").textContent` please note `inativebtn` != `iniativebtn`

Comment: Okay, its working! I don't know how I missed that typo, but regardless thank you sirs. For your question Elvis Pimentel, I am trying to make these elements duplicatable so that users can create as many  subgrids as they likes as opposed to a set number of grids. Again Thank you.